# How to cout list's values with iterator?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

The question is in the title, I have tried this as I used it in the past but it doesnt work now:

```
for (list<string>::iterator it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end(); it++){
    cout << *it;
}
```

The error is the following:

*"no operator "<<" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::ostream << std::string  "*

I havent used c++ like for 2 years and now Im stucked here, used google but didnt find any good answer.

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to include a header, most likely `<string>` (or, more unlikely, `<iostream>` or `<list>`). All three of those are required, you may not rely on any standard library header including another.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator<<` overloads for `std::string` are actually not found in `<iostream>` but in `<string>`. The standard does not restrict a library implementation from including arbitrary headers, so most implementations will include `<string>` somewhere up the chain. In the event that yours doesn't, you need to include `<string>` manually.